# What do ::before and ::after mean?

Tags: html, css

I was looking at a couple Twitter Bootstrap templates and I saw that a lot of `::before` and `::after` were inserted before and after `div` tags.

Can anybody tell me what they are?

Comment: Yes I know about pseudo elements but look at this example... http://cleancanvas.herokuapp.com/ There is a ::before and ::after around the navigation div and nothing is inserted. I saw that a couple times and was wondering about what it was.

Comment: In that example you've just given me, they have `display:table;` in their `::after` and `::before`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They represent pseudo-elements, which you don't include directly in your markup, but are available to you to create some neat effects with CSS. You have mentioned `::before` and `::after`, and they represent pseudo-elements that appear, shockingly, before and after your elements.

The whole list is included below and should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
::after 
::before 
::first-letter 
::first-line 
::selection
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Note the use of the double-colon, which is consistent with the spec. Sometimes you will see pseudo-elements specified with a single colon, but that was only because we needed to support browsers that didn't understand the double-colon syntax.

Comment: I knew about pseudo elements but never saw them written with double colons -> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp I thought it maybe meant something different. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

The `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements are for `css` and are in no way bootstrap specific.

A quick example of some of the stuff it can do is this:

Say you have a basic p element:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

In your css, if you had this:

```
p::before{
  content:'Hi';
}
```

The `p` tag in `html` would now say:

```
HiHello
```

If it was

```
p::after{
  content:'Hi';
}
```

It would be:

```
HelloHi
```

This can be very useful if you're using it with things such as phone numbers, or e-mail addresses e.g

```
p.phone_number::before{
  content:'Phone #: ';
}
```

`<p class='phone_number'>` would now have `Phone #:` before it.

You can do very many things, even use it for styling.

If you look at [The shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), you will see that it's used on the more complex shapes.

One thing that `::before` and `::after` have in common and MUST have to work, is the `content` attribute. If it doesn't have a content attribute it wont show up. Don't mistake this as having a blank `content`, though, as this will work provided you give it a height/width like any other element.

`::before` and `::after` aren't the only Pseudo elements though, here is a list:

```
::after
::before
::first-letter
::first-line
::selection
```

You can also double up on these elements:

For example:

```
p:hover::before{
  content:'Hovered! ';
}
```

Comment: Many in this list aren't pseudo-elements, but are pseudo-classes ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes