# What is the ::before or ::after expression, and why is it shown in the browser developer tools?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have read `::before` is used to add content before the element you use it with, e.g.

```
p::before { 
    content: "Read this: ";
}
```

but most of the times I have seen (peeking at web pages through developer tools) they use them without any element, e.g.

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
      ::before
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></button>
      </div>
      ::after
    </div>
```

Surprisingly when you look at web page source code these `::before` or `::after` elements are not displayed.

Why are they shown in developer tools?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719956/what-does-before-really-do ♦ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484020/what-do-before-and-after-mean

Answer (score 4):

CSS-Tricks:

> CSS has a property called content. It can only be used with the pseudo
>   elements :after and :before. It is written like a pseudo selector
>   (with the colon), but it's called a pseudo element because it's not
>   actually selecting anything that exists on the page but adding
>   something new to the page.

[::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) insert content before an element using css.

```
q::before { 
  content: "«";
  color: blue;
}
```

[::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) insert content after an element.

```
q::after { 
  content: "»";
  color: red;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lrh1627/)

you can use Special Characters too, some of them:

\2018 - Left Single Smart Quote

\2019 - Right Single Smart Quote

\00A9 - Copyright

\2713 - Checkmark

\2192 - Right arrow

\2190 - Left arrow

you can use element attributes too:

```
<a title="A web design community." href="http://css-tricks.com">CSS-Tricks</a>

a:before {
   content: attr(title) ": ";
}
```

read complete article [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/)

Comment: Not completely true: `::before` inserts content (text or text with images, but not HTML markup) before the *actual content* of the element (before its first child node, but still inside the element itself), similarly with `::after`, which inserts content after the actual content of the element (but still inside it).

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn I'd go beyond that and say "not true at all".

Comment: Just to make it obvious... `p:before` and `p:after` is essentially the same as `<p><span>I am :before</span>Contents of p<span>I am :after</span></p>` - The pseudo elements are *inside* the element they are assigned to.

Comment: The updated answer still doesn't explain the behavior of `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements properly. And the quoted phrase, also, is not relevant. The question is about why they are shown in Developer tools but are not shown in HTML source. This is because - obviously - you can't modify the content of a document by CSS. In fact, pseudo-elements are added into the DOM, not the HTML source.