# What's the ::before and ::after that I see in the HTML element inspector?

Tags: html, markup, pseudo-element

Our sites use markup like this in a few places:

```
<header class="row">
  ::before
  <h1 class="entry-title">Privacy Policy</h1>
  ::after
</header>
```

What does the `::before` and `::after` signify and how could I use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do ::before and ::after mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484020/what-do-before-and-after-mean)

Comment: Also: [What is the ::before or ::after expression, and why is it shown in the browser developer tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26433223/1591669)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not see those in markup.

You may see them in the element inspector in various browsers developer tools.

They represent [the before and after pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#gen-content) that you can generate with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The `::before` element inserts an html element before the given element, just as the `::after` element inserts an html element after the given element. (as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp), [try-it-yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before_style))

For example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
p::before {
    content: "Hello ";
}

p::after {
    content: "!";
}
```

This will result in `Hello World!` on your HTML page.